# Не учитывать символы внутри кода preg_match

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как можно не учитывать квадратные скобки внутри конструкции:

```
[display = "news"]
    <div class="box">
        <h3>[ТУТ] Похожие новости</h3>
    </div>
[/display]
```

Правило:

```
preg_match_all('/(\[display\s?=\s?\"(.+?)\"\])(.+?)(\[\/display\])/is', $str, $display);
```

Если внутри нет квадратных скобок, то все отображается как надо. Если скобки присутствуют, то на странице в итоге выведется весь код в месте с `[display = "news"]...[/display]`

Полный код:

```
[display = "news"]
<div class="box">
        <h3>Похожие новости</h3>
        <article class="related_news">
<header class="fx jc_fs">
    <img src="http://devs/public/uploads/camby/blog/news/06-2019/thumb/1559486818884_IMG_1805.JPG" alt="[KS] Downloader - скачивание файлов по таймеру" class="preview_related">
    <div class="related_content">
        <h2><a href="/7-ks-downloader---skachivanie-faylov-po-taymeru.html">[KS] Downloader - скачивание файлов по таймеру</a></h2>
        <div class="preview_text">Краткое описание</div>
        <span class="ico_date date_min">02.06.2019</span>
    </div>
</header>
</article><article class="related_news">
<header class="fx jc_fs">
    <img src="http://devs/public/uploads/camby/blog/news/05-2019/thumb/1557758138452_1477217493_rassvet_i_tuman.jpg" alt="Ещё одна новость" class="preview_related">
    <div class="related_content">
        <h2><a href="/2-esche-odna-novosty.html">Ещё одна новость</a></h2>
        <div class="preview_text">Тест 8</div>
        <span class="ico_date date_min">11.05.2019</span>
    </div>
</header>
</article><article class="related_news">
<header class="fx jc_fs">
    <img src="http://devs/public/uploads/camby/blog/news/06-2019/thumb/1559483918710_lun0294.jpg" alt="Ещё одна новость" class="preview_related">
    <div class="related_content">
        <h2><a href="/1-esche-odna-novosty.html">Ещё одна новость</a></h2>
        <div class="preview_text">Тест 7</div>
        <span class="ico_date date_min">11.05.2019</span>
    </div>
</header>
</article>
</div>
[/display]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вам не нравится в [вашем регулярном выражении](https://regex101.com/r/2msAEP/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ничего не понимаю, странно почему у меня не работает.

Comment: Очень странно, не могу разобраться. Если на сайте это делать, то у меня ошибка, как только убираю квадратные скобки, все отлично.

Comment: Приведите код, который у вас не работает.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Привел

Comment: Если в коде нет квадратных скобок, то все работает хорошо

Comment: Есть вариант делать замену `str_replace(['[', ']'], ['&#091;', '&#093;'], $title)` но это очень плохой вариант.

Comment: Что это за "полный код"? В нём [нет текста, который вы хотите найти](https://regex101.com/r/qi0oNF/1).